# Complex Xpage takes long for partial refreshs

Tags: performance, xpages, refresh, partial

I have a complex xpage with lots of nested custom controls. Everytime I execute a partial refresh it takes over 4 seconds to finish. If I remove the complexity it works just fine and is fast as wished.

I put a test on this complex Xpage and even with partial execution mode this simple test takes over 4 seconds to finish.

```
<xp:button value="Label" id="button1">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="refreshPanel" disableValidators="true" execMode="partial" execId="inputText1">
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
<xp:div id="refreshPanel">
    <xp:inputText id="inputText1"></xp:inputText>
</xp:div>
```

[execution time of partialrefresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiMbF.png)

Does anyone have a hint on this? Any server settings which can be adjusted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few little tweaks you can make to help speed things up (in general) however I'm not sure how they would help with a single complex page, but.....

- Change the server page persistence setting to keep the current page in memory
- Minimize the use of SSJS
- Partial Execution mode (which Knut has already mentioned)
- Support Concurrent User Load
- Keep the Maxheap size at ¼ of the available RAM
- For your XSP properties, enable “Use run-time optimized java script
  and CSS resources”
- Set your value bindings so they compute on the page load.

All of the above are tips/recommendations I've read from other developers over the years and I implement/try to implement myself where possible so might be worth trying some/all to see if it helps?

Comment: Thanks a lot Knut and Chris for your Support. Would mark both answers as the accepted one but only one is allowed. At least 'For your XSP properties, enable “Use run-time optimized java script and CSS resources”' did the trick. My Partial refreshs are now even faster than ever. Which downsites do I face with this change? RAM is filled with Xpages? How much does an Xpage cost in my RAM?

Comment: Hmmm, not sure if there are any obvious downsides? It basically just has your JS and CSS files combined into fewer file so reduces the number of  requests which should make the site load much faster. Actually, as I type I think I recall there MAY be an issue with relative URLS in your CSS? If that is the case, simply update the URL references

Comment: Sorry picked the wrong point which did the trick. 'Change the server page persistence setting to keep the current page in memory' was the one which helped me out.

Comment: In that case, the only downside I'm aware of is that you may get temporary memory leaks, but everything will be released at some point so it's nothing to worry about. Be careful with store EVERYTHING in memory as you'll run out if you have more than a couple of xpages.

Answer (score 5):

Even though it is a partial refresh *all* XPage controls' values are submitted to server. "partial" means in this case that only the label1 part returns to client. But it is a full *submit* and this might take time...

You can submit partially though. Add

```
execMode="partial" execId="button1"
```

to your eventHandler properties. This time only the execId's value gets submitted. Put in execId the id that needs to be submitted (maybe a panel) for this partial refresh.

[image]

Have a look [here](http://www.intec.co.uk/understanding-partial-execution-part-two-execution/) for more information on partial execution mode .

Comment: Dear Knut, I read the article but still all the fields are submitted to the Server and my partial refresh still takes about 4 seconds.

Comment: I changed my code above. Is that what you meant? This still submits all the fields on the page.

Comment: Your changed code looks good. Are you sure project was rebuilt?

Comment: Cleaned and rebuilt. I think it´s more of an issue about the complexity of my Xpage. I have one custom control which contains several other custom  controls which in turn consist of more custom controls. So the tree is getting really deep. If I comment out all of this the Partial refresh is perfectly fast. Is there a way to say the server not to process the whole tree? Is that what partial execution mode should do?

Comment: Yes, it should. We have complex XPages with cascaded custom controls too. Do you have time consuming code in XPage's events?

Comment: No, only a bit of csjs. Does the screenshot provided in my question give you any hint on what it could be? Seems like he is just waiting for the server to respond all the time.

Comment: Screenshot just shows that server is working. Do you see any suspicious on server console?

Comment: There are no suspicious events on the server console.

Comment: OK, then proceed with Chris' suggestions.